# Android Studio doesn't detect my LG G Stylo

Tags: usb-connection-mode

Thanks to help from this group, I was able to turn on USB debugging on my LG G Stylo phone. Now When I plug it in, Windows 8 detects it. Thing pops up asking me to choose what happens when the phone is plugged in, but it does not appear in the choose device dialog. It is empty, the device is not there.

I checked the device manager, and under portable devices it has it listed with the driver working OK, saying it came from Microsoft.

Comment: You might need to change the connection mode to PTP (happened on most of my phones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a site like. This [http://androidxda.com/download-lg-usb-drivers] and find a usb driver for your phone then install and try again. Because windows default drivers arent for debugging if I recall correctly